# How to conditionally assign connection style in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am currently working on a multi-fluid library in which I have coded physical components, connectors, boundary conditions, sensors, physical properties and so on... The fluid selection is currently based on an `Integer fluid` selection.

So far, I have been able to conditionally assign the color of the components' style based on `fluid` value.

Now, I want to go a step further and also conditionally assign the color of the connection. I know about [Stack Overflow - Assign specific connection style to connector in Modelica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906181/assign-specific-connection-style-to-connector-in-modelica) as I have already put it to good use.

So I defined the parameter `parameter Integer fluid=fluid` in the connector, so that it inherits the `fluid` value from the component. Then I assigned a conditional style on a rectangle as stated in the link above.

However, I end up with the following error: `mean circular equalities for conduite.C1.fluid`
(where "conduite" is the component and "C1" one of its connector)

I am currently a bit clueless.

**EDIT:**

**Initial approach:**

- In connector model:

  ```
   parameter Integer fluid=fluid "1: 1st fluid / 2: 2nd fluid";
  ```
- In component model:

  ```
   parameter Integer fluid=1 "1: 1st fluid / 2: 2nd fluid";
  ```

for both instances of the connector: in the `fluid` parameter cell, I leave the default `fluid` value.

- The obtained flat Modelica shed light on the circular equalities:

  ```
   parameter Integer conduite.C1.fluid = conduite.C1.fluid;
   parameter Integer conduite.C2.fluid = conduite.C2.fluid;
  ```

**Other approach, that works but is not satisfying:**

- In connector model:

  ```
   parameter Integer fluid=1 "1: 1st fluid / 2: 2nd fluid";
  ```
- In component model:

  ```
   parameter Integer fluid=1 "1: 1st fluid / 2: 2nd fluid";
  ```

  for both instances of the connector:
  in the `fluid` cell: I type `fluid` instead of the default `1` value.
- The obtained flat Modelica is what I actually wanted:

  ```
   parameter Integer conduite.C1.fluid = conduite.fluid;
   parameter Integer conduite.C2.fluid = conduite.fluid;
  ```

Why does not the default value `fluid` refer to the upper level parameter, whereas the locally overwritten value does?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand the question so I'm doing some guessing here: My assumption is, that propagation went wrong somehow.

Would the following code result in what you need? Note that neither component nor Example will work:

```
package MultiFluid "Some psydo-code that could help"
  connector Con
    parameter Integer fluid=1 "1: 1st fluid / 2: 2nd fluid";
  end Con;

  model Component
    parameter Integer fluid=1 "1: 1st fluid / 2: 2nd fluid";

    Con C1(fluid=fluid) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,-10},{-90,10}}), iconTransformation(extent={{-110,-10},{-90,10}})));
    Con C2(fluid=fluid) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-10},{110,10}}), iconTransformation(extent={{90,-10},{110,10}})));

  end Component;

  model Example
    Component component(fluid=2) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));
  end Example;
end MultiFluid;
```

gives the flat Modelica code for the Example:

```
model Example
  parameter Integer component.fluid = 2 "1: 1st fluid / 2: 2nd fluid";
  parameter Integer component.C1.fluid = component.fluid "1: 1st fluid / 2: 2nd fluid";
  parameter Integer component.C2.fluid = component.fluid "1: 1st fluid / 2: 2nd fluid";

end Example;
```

If my assumption is correct, the essential part is the propagation of the `Integer fluid` from the `parameter` in `Component`:

```
Con C1(fluid=fluid)
```

This line passes the actual value from `Component` to the instances `C1` of `Con`.